# Twisted Python for responding multiple clients at a time

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

I have a problem. I'm having a echoserver which will accept clients and process his requirement and it returns the result to client.

Suppose I have two clients and 1 client requirement processing time would be 10 sec and 2 client requirement processing time would be 1 sec.

So when both clients connected to server at a time. how to run both the clients tasks at a time parallely and return the response to specific client which ever finishes first.

I have read that we can achieve this problem using python twisted. I have tried my luck, but Im unable to do it.

Please help me out of this Issue

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html and https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html

Comment: I have tried with server and client logics, but when two clients are connected at a time, server is processing 2nd client only after processing 1st client. Im not getting how to serve both clients at a time. Any sample code would be appreciated

Comment: please include an example of what you've tried

Comment: https://trinket.io/python/87fd18ca9e. Please go through my code "Server.py (acts as a server)" and 2 clients(client1 and client2.py). Client1 has a list of 10 numbers, whereas Client2 has a list of 1 number. Server will accept both clients and perform factorial of numbers and return the results.

When both clients are connected parallely, Im unable to process both clients at a time

Answer (score 1):

Your code (https://trinket.io/python/87fd18ca9e) has many mistakes in terms of async design patterns, but I will only address the most blatant mistake. There are a few calls to `time.sleep()`, this is blocking code and is causing your code to stop until the sleep function is done running. The number 1 rule it async programming is **do not use blocking functions**! Don't worry, this is a very common mistake and the Twisted and Python async communities are there to help you :) I'll give you a naive solution for your server:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol, defer, task

def sleep(n):
    return task.deferLater(reactor, n, lambda: None)

class QuoteProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.numConnections += 1

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def recur_factorial(self,n):
        fact=1
        print(n)
        for i in range(1,int(n)+1):
            fact=fact*i
        yield sleep(5)    # async sleep
        defer.returnValue(str(fact))

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        try:
            number = int(data)      # validate data is an int
        except ValueError:
            self.transport.write('Invalid input!')
            return                  # "exit" otherwise

        # use Deferreds to write to client after calculation is finished
        deferred_factorial = self.recur_factorial(number)
        deferred_factorial.addCallback(self.transport.write)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.numConnections -= 1

class QuoteFactory(Factory):
    numConnections = 0

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return QuoteProtocol(self)

reactor.listenTCP(8000, QuoteFactory())
reactor.run()
```

The main differences are in `recur_factorial()` and `dataReceived()`. The `recur_factorial()` is now utilizing `Deferred` (search how [`inlineCallbacks`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#inline-callbacks-using-yield) or coroutine's works) which allows for functions to execute after the result is available. So when the data in received, the factorial is calculated, then written to the end user. Finally there's the new `sleep()` function which allows for an async sleep function. I hope this helps. Keep reading the Krondo blog.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code but anyhow client2 is getting completed only after completion of client1 task. Can't it be done parallely at a time and return which ever is completed first

Comment: How are you running the client scripts? The factorial function is fast so you might not notice if it finishes before going to the next execution. As far as parallel execution goes, you'll need to use threads or processes. If the algorithm is small, I'd suggest optimizing using concurrent/async design because it is safer.